# System not booting due to upgrade failure from 16.04 to 18.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade

I recently tried upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 but the update hung up before completing.  I had to quit the upgrade and restart.  Now the computer boots to a black screen.  I tried opening the GRUB menu by tapping the *tab* button, but this doesn't work for me!  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interrupting a release-upgrade is among the most damaging things you can do to your system.

For users with the proper skill, this is sometimes recoverable and sometimes not - it depends upon exactly which packages were being istalled at the moment of interruption.

Most users who suffer from an interrupted release-upgrade find that a clean install is the fastest and easiest way to return to a functioning Ubuntu system.

Use a LiveUSB to preserve your data on to some other media.

Then use the LiveUSB to reinstall Ubuntu.